# Changing the basic functionality of Kendo Grid(like how filtering, sorting works)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

In my code, i am trying to implement a Kendo Grid with backend as jayData(working on around 50000 data).

Backend code is only giving me a limited data as once and everytime i change subfilter or sort, i have to call backend function to do the given query and give me the new data.

In the process, my grid is being refresh and hence i lose that subfilter query in the grid UI. 
Same goes for grouping also.

How can i implement a kendo grid where queries regarding grid data is done on backend code(hence overriding grid default functionality) and i dont lose my grid instance also.

Note:- My functions take 2 input, one being table columns for the grid and other being data in json format to be displayed in grid.

Comment: Please add some code to show how you're creating and updating your grid.

Comment: Nevermind, i found the mistake. I used transport read and callback to update grid data so solve it up.